# Woocommerce Hide Sale Flash for selected variations that are not on sale

Tags: css, woocommerce, product

I am currently hiding the woocommerce sale flash for variable products using css on the single product page like below:

```
.product-type-variable .onsale {
    display: none;
}
```

**Problem:**
I would now like to conditionally display the on sale flash message. So when a variation is selected on the single product page that's actually on sale, then the sale badge should display otherwise it shouldn't display.

Would it be possible to do this?

Comment: If you have conditions then use Javascript. **(1)** Get the element that represents the "sale bade" by its ID. Maybe put into a variable called `saleBadge` **(2)** Then using an **IF/Else** statement, try something like `saleBadge.style.visibility = "hidden";` or ``saleBadge.style.visibility = "visible";` depending on which one you need...

Comment: **PS**: It's not obvious how you are _"Currently hiding the WooCommerce sale flash for variable products using CSS"_ Don't be surprised if no one can Answer you without knowing what code you already wrote and what variables you are working with. If possible try to **show a basic example** that recreates the situation of your problem then it can be edited to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem. Got help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54965487/get-currently-selected-variation-and-data-from-woocommerce-variable-product)

```
/**
 * Function to display variations sale prices only when a variation on sale is selected
 * 
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation', 'action_wc_before_single_variation' );
function action_wc_before_single_variation() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
        // Check for the show_variation event that triggers when a variation is selected.
        $('form.variations_form').on('show_variation', function(event, data){
            //If variation is on sale, display the sale badge
            if(data.display_price < data.display_regular_price){
                $(".product-type-variable .onsale").css("display", "block");
            }
            //Otherwise hide the sale badge
            else {
                $(".product-type-variable .onsale").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes into the functions.php file of the active theme(Use child theme so that code isn't overwritten when theme is updated).*